# /usr/bin/ld - cannot find lib

Tags: command-line, compiling

I am compiling from source and I have the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lct
```

How to fix it? Thanks.
I tryed:

```
sudo apt-get install libxt-dev
```

But it doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the following commands would install expected `ct` library.

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-bin freetds-dev freedts-common
```